# How to generate groups of 10 consecutive numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to generate a list of consecutive numbers in groups of ten.  For example, let's start with a list of 109 numbers:

```
mylist = range(1,110,1)
```

I know that I can generate a list of intervals of 10 by using `range(1,110,10)`, which yields:

```
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101]
```

How can I generate a list of consecutive numbers in groups of ten like the following?

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], ...]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[range(i, i + 10) for i in range(1, 102, 10)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> [range(i, i + 10) for i in range(1, 102, 10)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50], [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60], [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70], [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80], [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90], [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100], [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110]]
>>> pprint(_)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
 [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
 [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
 [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70],
 [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80],
 [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90],
 [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100],
 [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110]]
```

Comment: One of many reasons to use [IPython](http://ipython.org/); I can just type this code and get the same output as in Cyber's answer, because it pretty-prints the repr of each expression you type at the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested list comprehensions to generate lists like this.

```
[[10*i + j for j in range(1,11)] for i in range(10)]
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
 [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
 [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
 [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70],
 [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80],
 [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90],
 [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can group them together.

```
def grouper(iterable, n):
    # from itertools recipes
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)] * n)

full_range = range(1, 101)

grouped_list = list(grouper(full_range,10))
```

Which results in:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
 (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
 (21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30),
 (31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40),
 (41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50),
 (51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60),
 (61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70),
 (71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80),
 (81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90),
 (91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)]
# a list of tuples, if you need it to be a list of lists:
# [list(group) for group in grouper(full_range, 10)]
```

Comment: What's the final list comprehension for? `x for x in y` without any expression on the `x` or any `if` clauses doesn't do anything useful, it's just a slow way of copying `y`. (If you're trying to make this 3.x-compatible and ensure it's a list even though `zip` doesn't return one anymore, just use `list(…)`.)

Comment: Well, your last comment in the example does a good job of making the comprehension useful. :)

Comment: @abarnert crud it's useful! I'm becoming known for needlessly preferring obfuscating map/filter to list comps! Better change that to `list(map(list, list(grouper(full_range, 10))))`. The extra call to list is SUPER important.

Comment: Didn't you mean `list(map(list, list(grouper(list(full_range), 10))))`? Or maybe `list(list((map,))[0](list, list(list((grouper,))[0](list(full_range), list(range(10))[-1]+1))))`? :)

Comment: @abarnert In all seriousness, I solved a programming challenge the other week with something like `reversed(zip(*map(list,zip(grouper(some_string.splitlines(), n)))))`

Comment: @abarnert Just looked it up, it was: `yield from grouper(map(some_function, recursive_flattener(zip(*map(functools.partial(grouper, n=2), some_string.splitlines()))))), 4)`

Comment: I would have given some of those intermediate iterators names and split it into 3 statements, but I probably would have written something similar otherwise. After all, the best way to write `2` without making any assumptions about number representations is `next(consume(consume(count(), 1), 1))`, right?

Comment: @abarnert for sure! ;). Honestly the problem was incredibly simple but I wanted to solve it using grouping zips for no good reason. Had to group two lines into 2x2 squares e.g. `"1234\n5678"` -> `[['1','2','5','6'], ['3','4','7','8']]`.